# HttpClient injected into a singleton

Tags: .net-core

I am currently using a TypedClient and just want to better understand issues with singletons and how the HttpClientFactory works.

After reading the articles from [Steve Gordon](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore) I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly and using the correct approach.

I have a client which is registered using `services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>`.

```cs
public class MyClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public MyClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

I also have a background service, which is a singleton, registered using `services.AddSingleton<IMyBackgroundService, MyBackgroundService>()`

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService : IMyBackgroundService
{
    private MyClient _myClient;

    public MyBackgroundService(MyClient myClient)
    {
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
}
```

would the instance of `_myClient` within the singleton `MyBackgroundService` not also just be a singleton in practice?

---

If I have a background method called `DoJob` would it not be better to create a scope in `DoJob` and then inject `HttpClientFactory` and request a instance of `MyClient`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your `MyBackgroundService` should not be a singleton, but a scoped.

I think it's either that or inject your `MyClient` directly in the controller, otherwise as you said, the instance of `MyClient` will become a singleton.

Comment: `MyBackgroundService` will be a singleton because it lasts the entire lifecycle of thje application. I can, however, create a scope in each method and simply use the IOC manually. Even if the MyBackgroundService was scoped it would still be created once in the lifecycle of the application and would, therefore, still be a singleton in practice.

Comment: @Questioning not sure I follow you here, if your MyBackgroundService was scoped it would be created once per request, if it's a singleton it is created once and reused in further requests, it's not the same, check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes

Comment: This is not in the context of webrequests, it is a background service. The `MyBackgroundService` is instantiated once and has a single instance. It is requested once, not multiple times. The question really boils down to whether the `HttpClient` should exist as a singleton, scoped or transient.

Comment: Oh got it, I was assuming all the time we were talking about asp.net core. In that case I'm not sure it makes any difference...

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference then you're advocating for using the HttpClient as a singleton. I'll try to do more reading elsewhere and update the answer when I find out what the suggested method is.